# Unable to send email

Tags: mobile-safari

I receive a msg "the recipient was rejected by the server because the user is unknown" when trying to send an email from me.com to icloud.com. Recipient is in Italy but I have no problem sending to hotmail.com in Italy

Comment: 'user is unknown' is a pretty clear rejection reason. The server doesn't have an account by that name.

Comment: In other words... The first half of the email address is wrong or contains a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you received is simple to understand.  The email address is invalid.